# Clone / Copy a SimpleScriptContext

Tags: multithreading, java-8, nashorn

Today I have used ScriptContext to create thread-safety with a single nashorn engine used across multiple threads, however it it is pretty expensive to create many contexts since each context must also eval my base JS libs.

Is there a way to copy / clone a ScriptContext (SimpleScriptContext) that already has some base bindings and once copied, add some additional bindings to it, while maintaining thread-safety?

Or, is there an alternative way to accomplish this for better performance, perhaps cloning / copying the Bindings and using context.setBindings()?  Or Cloning / copying the Map underlying the Bindings object and using the SimpleBindings(map) constructor?

Comment: I tried using SimpleBindings copy constructor to start from an existing Bindings and the use context.setBindings, but the results were not thread-safe.

Comment: SimpleBindings does not have a copy constructor. It just uses the map instance that you pass to store the mappings. It does not effectively copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the bindings before each execution and add it to the global context and subsequently to the ScriptEngine. This would mean that there has to be a global copy of bindings that has common mapping that all your JavaScript executions require. These binding are copied and used in a context-engine combination before every execution so that local mapping does not interfere with the mappings inside the global binding.

Having said that, i would refrain from using a single engine to service all the threads since the Nashorn ScriptEngine is not threadsafe. I would recommend using one engine per thread.

There are stack overflow posts that do say that ScriptEngine is infact threadsafe but i have faced some serious crosstalk issues while using one engine with bindings copied into it for every call.

Also note that, Bindings.copyAll() will not ensure consistent behavior among JavaScript objects. You might encounter issues while JSON.stringifying objects that were part of a copied mapping, inside your JavaScript code.

EDIT: From the comments to this answer from @DennisKrøger ,ScriptContext instances should be used instead of Bindings to overcome crosstalk.

Comment: The Nashorn ScriptEngine should be (and is in my experience) thread safe. You probably used bindings directly instead of contexts with the bindings set to them.

At least that's what I did, and I had terrible threading issues until I switched to using contexts.

Comment: @DennisKrøger Thanks but unfortunately like you, we also were late to realize that using contexts is the way to go. For now, we overcome threadsafety issues by declaring some objects as ThreadLocal. A longterm and permanent fix would be to manipulate contexts instead.